# Can Covid-19 virus be simply filtered out from infected patient’s blood?

Tags: coronavirus

Can Covid-19 virus be simply filtered out from infected patient’s blood?
If a Covid+ patient’s blood is passed through a filter, say 100 nm or a system of filters, 100 nm and 500 nm can we isolate the virus from serum including small and large blood particles? This is somewhat like a dialysis of the blood. I am particularly interested to know if graphene filters will be of help here. Has somebody worked on that? I am thinking if size can be exploited to isolate the virus (irrespective of mutants) and aid the primary treatment of the patient. I am not a virologist and new to the subject.

Answer (score 5):

No, this wouldn't work, and if you think about it for a bit you'll see why. First and foremost, your 100nm filter would catch all the cells that are in the blood. Therefore, all you'd end up with is plasma, and the patient would die within several minutes of beginning "therapy" due to not being able to transport oxygen with red blood cells. On a practical note, all those cells would clog your filters, of any size, immediately.

Another reason: SARS-CoV-2 primarily infects epithelial cells in the respiratory system, and can easily transfer from cell to cell without having to use the bloodstream. In fact, it's my understanding that the serum load of virus is actually rather low. Filtering the blood wouldn't prevent any of that cell->cell transfer.

Final reason (for now): there are other things in the blood that are in the vicinity of the same size as virus particles - cholesterol/lipoprotein aggregates, larger protein complexes, platelets, etc. You'd lose all these vital components of your body with any kind of filtering scheme.

Comment: Thank you.

I was suggesting a system of three filters, 800 nm, 200 nm and 100 nm in that order. Infected blood passing through this system will isolate the virus while retaining the useful constituents of the blood. I agree that there may be blood constituents in the same size range as the virus which should be identified and replenished back. I also agree that the larger problem is in the epithelial cells which should be addressed by standard vaccination. To avoid filter clogging, if filtering is done in small quantities of blood at a time then it may not be a problem. Let me refine this.

Comment: Feel free to revise your design, but trust me - there are reasons why this is not a clinical therapy, for viral infections or anything else. I've laid out some above, but there are others. Filtering small amounts of blood at a time won't work, b/c you're always going to lose something important when you filter. Even if you can get 95% of the RBCs back, there's still that 5% gone each time, and there'd have to be many, *many* rounds if you want to reduce the whole viral load appreciably. It's just not a good idea.